# Specific runtime environment commands doesn't work in SSH.NET

Tags: c#, .net, ssh, cisco

I'm using [SSH.NET](http://sshnet.codeplex.com/) to connect (with username + password) to a server and run some commands.
Connection to server is made to manage some components via Cisco Application Control Software, but that shouldn't matter because command are sent as they are.

Connection to server works well, all other commands work too but two specific commands doesn't work, and I can't seem to understand why.
The commands that fail are: `changeto Production` and `terminal length 0`.
My code is pretty simple (simplified for the question, but same flow):

```
using (var client = new SshClient(serverIP, port, username, password)
{
    client.Connect();
    var cmd = Client.RunCommand("terminal length 0");
    cmd = client.RunCommand("changeto Production");
    // Other command follow
}
```

While running the same commands via putty it works, and no, `changeto` shouldn't be `change to`.
I think the problem here is changing scopes (changeto Production) via code, but can't understand why.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: is changeto an alias sourced in login shell profile? have you tried to source your ~/.bash_profile?

Comment: What do you mean? Where is that file located? When I run this command (via code) it doesn't produce any error, it just acts like command was executed successfully but the action doesn't happen. Via putty it works (without any files as far as I know, I downloaded it just for test purpose).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After searching and asking on the CodePlex forum of the SSH.NET library, I understood the problem: the `RunCommand()` function creates a new shell every call.
The new shell is created with default environment, and because `terminal length 0` and `changeto Production` change the runtime-environment for following commands, this can't be accomplished with `RunCommand()`.
I ended up writing and reading directly from the shell stream (using `SshClient.CreateShellStream()`) and playing with `Expect()` to get and parse the output I need. This way all commands are executed in the same shell.